# How to make the script waiting for a promise result before continue on?

Tags: javascript

I've been struggle trying to find a solutions for this one.

I have a promise that waiting to fetch user information from an external server, and then decide which page to redirect to next.  However, my script is not waiting for the promise to return, but keep on executing the next line of code, which redirect to a wrong page, and then, once the promise return, it redirect again to the correct page.

What I want, is the code to wait for the promise and base on that returned data, then redirect to the correct page.

```
function redirect(user){

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     //send request to external server and waiting for the response
     //if response == 1 then redirect to page1

  }
}

redirect(user).then(() => {
   //redirect to page 2 here
});
```

However, the result is always redirect to page2 then redirect to page1

Comment: Please show the *actual code* of `redirect`, not psuedo-code, so we can see what the problem might be

Answer (score 1):

Here is the an example about promise usage

```js
function redirect(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(user)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => resolve(data.data))
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
  })
}

redirect("https://reqres.in/api/users/2").then((data) => {
  // You should make redirection here
  /*
  if(data == 1) {
    // your operation
  } else {
    // another operation
  }
  */
  console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `redirect` must also wait for the request to finish. Without the detailed implementation, I presume you did not have the `await` for the sever request.

I'm guessing some of your implementation here.

https://jsfiddle.net/4g6juyf5/1/

```
function redirect(user) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // Wait for the first page to finish
    const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');

    // finished then resolve
    if (result != undefined) {
      console.log("Page 1 requested")
      resolve(true)
    }
  })
}

const user = "John";

redirect(user).then(async () => {
  //redirect to page 2 here
  console.log("Requesting Page 2")
  const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
});
```

Note, this code is still pretty sloppy. If you post your implementation, we might be able to improve it.